# Best way to pass values from popup page to parent page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a main page for customer in which i need to select location for the customer . to pick a location we have desined a popup page which has a grid which displays all locations . once user pics the loction that particular location should be returned back to the main page .

Location object contains feilds - LocId,LocName,LocState,LocCountry,PinCode  .
The entire location object should be returned to the main page not a single value .

My code for opening location is

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton2" runat="server" ImageUrl="../Content/Images/search.png" Height="21px" ToolTip="Search Location" Width="21px"
                        OnClientClick="ShowLocation();" />
```

---

```
function ShowLocation() {
    window.showModalDialog('../StandardLookups/Location.aspx', '_blank', 'dialogWidth:820px; dialogHeight:400px; dialogLeft:250px; dialogTop:250px;status:no; scroll:no; help:no; resizable:no,edge: Raised,doPostBackAfterCloseCallback: false,postBackElementId: null');

}
```

---

Code in popup window once the row is selected by the user

```
 protected void btnSelect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<object> locationValues = gvLocationLookup.GetSelectedFieldValues(new string[] { "LocId", "LocName", "LocState","LocCountry","PinCode" });

        var locationValue = (object[])locationValues[0];

        var location= new Location
        {
            LocId = (int?)locationValue[0],
            LocName = (string)locationValue[1],
            LocState = (string)locationValue[2]
            LocCountry = (string)locationValue[3]
            PinCode =   (string)locationValue[4]
        };
        Session["SELECTED_LOCATION"] = location;
        Response.Write("<script> window.opener.location.reload(false); window.close();</" + "script>");
        Response.End();
    }
```

Currently i use sessions values to move values . Is there any better approaches ?

Answer (score 0):

You can check here what method suits to your needs.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I've created a system like this before, using only client side code (javascript, no C#).
The requirement was that, when filling in a form, a specific value (e.g. a location) could be selected in a popup. 
Once the value was clicked in the popup, the parent page receives this information through javascript, and the popup closes itself.

Note that the parent page must have the needed fields to be filled. In my case it is an autocomplete textbox (=FieldName) and a linked HiddenField (=FieldName_key), which holds the unique key to the text in the textbox.

```
function confirmSelection(code, key)
{
    try {
        window.opener.document.getElementById('<%= FieldName %>').value = code;
        window.opener.document.getElementById('<%= FieldName %>_key').value = key;
        window.close();
    }
    catch (e) {window.close();}
}
```

An additional benefit of this client-side script (opposed to the C# script) is that you don't have to reload the parent page, which can disturb your user in his/her work.